# Contact form 7 to external API

Tags: php, wordpress, api

I am trying to connect Contact Form 7 in wordpress to a external API following this instructions:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QOjpqHFM9v8&ab_channel=TechiePress

I need to add authorization to access to the API like in the screenshot attached.

Any help would be great
Thanks in advance

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TUue.jpg

```
function techiepress_cf7_api_sender( $contact_form) {
    $title = $contact_form->title;

    if ($title === 'Web Response' ) {
        $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

        if ( $submission )  {
            $posted_data = $submission->submission->get_posted_data();

            $name = $posted_data['your-name'];
            $email = $posted_data['your-email'];
            $telefon = $posted_data['your-phone'];
            $adress = $posted_data['your-message'];
            $postnummer = $posted_data['number-777'];

            $url = '';

            $args = array (
                'body' => array(
                    'name' => $name,
                    'email' => $email,
                    'telefon' => $telefon,
                    'adress' => $adress,
                    'postnummer' => $postnummer,
                    
                )

            );

            wp_remote_post( $url, $args);

            return;  ´´´


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1Eca.png
```

Answer (score 0):

We have a solution that can integrate Contact Form 7 with an external API.

It is a plugin available in the directory:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpgetapi/

And here is an article outlining how WPGetAPI integrates with CF7:
https://wpgetapi.com/docs/using-with-contact-form-7/